# Print to PDF (A3 landscape) export size ends up at 160cm x 110cm

Tags: excel, vba

I have large spreadsheet that I'm looping through and printing each page to a pdf report.

I'm trying to print them A3 Landscape, however the actual export size is far larger than an A3 page.

Any suggestions I what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub printChartsA3()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sPrintArea As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Const path As String = "E:\A3 Charts\"

    sPrintArea = "A1:BM69"

    For Each wks In Worksheets

            Application.PrintCommunication = False

            wks.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
            wks.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
            wks.PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            wks.PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            wks.PageSetup.PrintArea = sPrintArea
            wks.PageSetup.Zoom = False
            wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
            'wks.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1 'not sure if this one is needed?

            Application.PrintCommunication = True

            wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=path & wks.Name & ".pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next

    Set wks = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving the `wks.PageSetup.Zoom = False` line just after the `Application.PrintCommunication = False`, so it is the first line of `PageSetup` settings

Comment: Tried, but still getting the same result.